# How do I make the web server run "constantly"?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-ec2

I have a Play application at ec2 which I just have deployed. Everything seems fine, it's visible in the Internet. However, it seems fine only as the server is working. What I mean is that when I connect to ec2 via ssh  and then launch the server by `play run`, only since then it's visible in the Internet and **works fine**. I know it's obvious. But I tried to run it in background by `play run&` and it never worked:

```
$ play run &
[1] 2470

$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 play run

$ play run&
[2] 2494

$ jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 play run
[2]+  Stopped                 play run
```

Have I been doing something wrong? But what and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prepare your application for production [as discussed in the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/Production). You might also consider [running it behind Nginx or Apache or another web server](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/HTTPServer).

Comment: thansk, I missed that for some reason. However, what it weren't a Play application but Rails or PHP, would I have to run the server with "&"?

Comment: @Grienders It varies a bit by platform. With php, since there isn't really an application server, the scripts will execute directly out of the folder you put them in. However you may configure php as fcgi which could result in php being a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

Besides also recommending running production using a reverse proxy with Apache or Nginx. (Pretty much the de facto standard these days on Linux), you can also deploy it using the `play dist` command. Basically, it will compile your code into a package and put it into a zip file.

You can unzip your zip file wherever you want to run your application then you can just run it with:

```
$ ./<yourapplication>/bin/<yourapplication> -Dhttp.port=<whichever port you want to run it at> &
```

Make sure you have the `java` executable in your PATH and this method will avoid having any dependency with the Play application itself.  Eventually, you'll probably want to create a  Linux init script if you need to deploy your app into multiple servers say behind a load balancer -- So you can your just run `service <your-app> start` or `service <your-app> stop`

More info here:  http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ProductionDist.

Also, make sure you look at the latest play documentation as it gets updated pretty often.